# I have to pass data from an activity to a class file what way i can do it in android

Tags: android

I have to pass data from an activity to a class file what way i can do it in android.i want to pass data list View for where clause in DATA HANDLER Class.

Comment: The other class is an activity to?

Comment: What is `a class file`? `i want to pass data list View for where clause in DATA HANDLER Class.` Sorry I can't make up anything from this